# django login Exception Value: 'unicode' object is not callable

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to setup a login using django and bootstrap found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632831/django-login-form-in-bootstrap-popup) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183162/login-form-in-dropdown-bootstrap-on-django-project)

my views.py

```
def LoginRequest(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
            else:
                return render_to_response('/', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render_to_response('/', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render_to_response('/', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my urls.py

```
from core.views import LoginRequest, LogoutRequest, ContactRequest

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/$', 'LoginRequest'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'LogoutRequest'),
```

my forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(label=(u'Email'), max_length=30)
    password = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False), max_length=30)
```

And the snippet from my index.html -

```
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a href={% url 'dashboard' %}>Dashboard</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Login<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
          <form action='/login/' method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
            {% if form.errors %}
                {{ form.errors}}
            {% endif %}
            <label for="id_email">Login:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="id_email">
            <br />
            <label for="id_password">Pass:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password">
            <br />
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login" />
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ '/dashboard' }}" />
        </form>
       </div>
       </li>
     {% endif %}
```

As soon as I hit "login" I get the following traceback -

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /login/
Exception Value: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your urls file, you need to remove the string around the view names.

Like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/$', LoginRequest), #Shred the quotes
    url(r'^logout/$', LogoutRequest), #Shred the quotes
```

Note that the new [django recommended way is](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial04/#amend-urlconf):

```
from core import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/$', views.LoginRequest),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.LogoutRequest),
```

Also, you can simplify your view like this:

```
def LoginRequest(request):

    redirect_to = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/')
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    return render_to_response('/', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Also, `/` needs to be something like: `/index.html` - depends on where the template is located.

Comment: Thanks that did it.  separate issue now is it's complaining that `TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/`

Comment: `render_to_response` expects the template name as the first argument. You are providing it the path, which is the issue

Comment: thnx.  making a new question I've removed render_to_response and get the same error.