# django TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/

Tags: django

I'm trying to login using a form setup here -

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576801/django-login-exception-value-unicode-object-is-not-callable#31576801`

When clicking login I get the following traceback -

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/opt/datapi/core/views.py" in LoginRequest
  47.     return render_to_response('/',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render_to_response
  23.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  170.         t = get_template(template_name, dirs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  144.     template, origin = find_template(template_name, dirs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  136.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/
Exception Value: /
```

This is my view -

```
def LoginRequest(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
            else:
                return render_to_response('/', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render_to_response('/', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render_to_response('/', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I can only imaging the template doesn't exist because it's not a template.  what I'm trying to do is get my view to login and then just return me to the root url.

Comment: what is the location of your index file? ALso, as i mentioned earlier, i still see the `/` in place of the `index.html`

Comment: I see what you mean now, so setting to index.html gets rid of any errors.  I am seeing the username and password pass into the view and I get a 200 response, but when it redirects to my index.html it's not keeping me logged in...  It should be showing as authenticated when the index.html loads as per `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`

Comment: reverted to my old view and it works... I can work with this for now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to pass a `template_name` in `render_to_response`. You are not doing that but instead passing a `url`.**

Basic signature of `render_to_response`:

```
render_to_response(template_name[, context][, context_instance][, content_type][, status][, dirs][, using])
```

This will render a given `template` with a given `context` dictionary and returns an `HttpResponse` object with that rendered text.

So below statement should not be:

```
return render_to_response('/', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but instead be something like:

```
return render_to_response('template_name_of_index_page', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to revert to the following view -

```
def LoginRequest(request):
    active = "index"
    message = ""
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data['email']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
                if user is not None and user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard')
                else:
                    message = "user and/or password incorrect"


    ctx = {'active':active, 'form': form}
    return render_to_response('index.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and now no issues.